# Unable to add array data to MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have 2 URLs, one points to a different connection string and the other to local MongoDB instance. While I establish the connection to MongoDB using MongoClient with `url1` and fetch the required data from a DB/collection and lastly store it in an array.
Now I want to insert this array to a localhost MongoDB collection and on doing so I get `MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect` error.

app.js

```
var url1="someurl but not localhost";
var url2="mongodb://localhost:27017/";
router.get('/route1', function(req, res)
{
    MongoClient.connect(url1,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("customer");
        dbo.collection("customer_report").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err!=null){
            console.log("Connection Failed!!"+err)
          }
          var customerArray =[];
          for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            backupArray.push({
                a: result[i].a,
                b: result[i].b,
                c: result[i].c,
                d: result[i].d,
            });    
          }
        console.log(customerArray);
        res.json({content:customerArray});
        db.close();
        MongoClient.connect(url2,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db1) { 
            //Trying to establish another mongodb connection wuth new url
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("localdb");
            dbo.collection("localcollection").insertMany(customerArray, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
                db1.close();
            });
        });
        });
    }); 
});
```

And if I don't close `db.close();` then the array data gets appended to first MongoDB collection and not the local MongoDB. Looking for a solution to handle two MongoClient at the same time or a way to insert the customerArray to local MongoDB collection.

Is there a workaround where I can add the array elements to my local MongoDB collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second mongo connect block I think you want

`var dbo = db.db("localdb");`

to be

`var dbo = db1.db("localdb");`

Comment: It worked! My bad I completely ignored the possibility and was always focused on whether we can have two routes pointing to direct uri.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure those credentials work in console commands? And have you made sure the last connection through the console is closed before trying to use them in the script?